# Simple MySQL function error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a MySQL function which returns whether an username is in my table or not. It's the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION UserExists (pUserName VARCHAR(40))
RETURNS BIT DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN

DECLARE rVal BIT;

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userName = pUserName)
THEN SET rVal = 1;
ELSE SET rVal = 0;
END IF;

RETURN rVal;

END;
```

However, I get an error. Any ideas?

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userName = pUserName))
```

Answer (score 1):

how about using user define variable?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION UserExists (pUserName VARCHAR(40))
RETURNS BIT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    DECLARE rVal BIT;
    SET @recCount := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE userName = pUserName);
    IF @recCount > 0 THEN 
        SET rVal = 1;
    ELSE 
        SET rVal = 0;
    END IF;
    RETURN rVal;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, didn't work either. Error: #1419 - You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

Comment: the error is not the syntax but because *maybe* you don't have enough privilege to create a function.

Comment: I have a shared godaddy hosting account. Any idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Before you query your mysql database, you need to use %mysql sudo -u  -p and then give your commands.